# Can I put a Tortec Epic rear rack on a 27" frame?

Tags: touring, compatibility, build, panniers, vintage

I'm reviewing racks for my newly re-built vintage tour bike. I have 126mm drops.   I'm guessing I can just use spacers/washers to get the width lined up,  but the it's listed as 26", so if there isn't clearance for the tire,  is there some simple way to raise the mount,  like some steel thingy with two holes in it and a little gap?  I don't have a lot of tools or shop space, so I need something ready made.  *I am in Hiroshima and there are not a lot of rack options I've been able to find locally.

I want this rack as it is well priced,  people seem to have good luck with them, it's steel and has a nice payload capacity.  I haven't seen anything that hits all of these points so I will make it work if I can.

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen setups jury-rigged using [repair straps](http://www.thehardwarehut.com/images/moreimages/legandcornerbraces-miscfurniturecomponents/stanley-nationalhardware/sta-n272-732-big.jpg) from a hardware store.  Would probably require drilling out the holes, though.

Comment: I guess you're talking about those straps that come rolled up on a wheel, the ones with the holes on them? If so,  I thought about that idea as well, But I think I need something more rigid in order to obtain clearance if that is necessary. I'm concerned that doubling them up might be unsightly, though likely it would work in a jam.

Comment: No, these are quite stiff, and come in fixed lengths.

Comment: Maybe I'll go on a "Daiki" (Japanese Hardware shop)  Safari and see what I can dig up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean [this rack](http://www.zyro.co.uk/tortec/products/detail/TTEPIC)? On the linked page it says that the rack will fit a 700c bike. Also I see that there are two holes at the bottom (dropout) mount, that would make it easy to use something like a repair strap to raise the rack if that proves necessary. Use a bolt through both holes so that the repair strap and rack can't move under load.

If you're handy with tools you might find it just as easy to get a short piece of stainless flat bar (or aluminum) and cut and drill it yourself.

Comment: Yes, that rack. can you link a pic of what repair strap I might look for?  I'm excellent with tools,  but having just moved to Japan I have scant resources, so I need to get this working with basics, no dremels et al.  And I need to get the rack going soon.  Thanks!

Comment: Based on the product description, I don't think you're going to need a repair strap. I think they are saying it will just fit.

Comment: Everything I've read only mention fitting 700 or 26",  both of which smaller than my 27.  I've looked over options and I think I'm satisfied I can buy it and adapt if necessary..  we're talking about possibly 1/2 inch of extra  clearance.

Comment: @Brendan 700C and 27" are quite similar -- close enough that a fat tyre on a 700C could make for a larger diameter than a thin tyre on a 27".

Comment: @Brendan I'd missed that you were running 27" rather than 700c wheels, sorry for any confusion that that caused. as Chris H points out, the two sizes are very similar – if you look at the ISO (ETRTO) sizes of the two the bead seat diameter (roughly speaking the inner diameter of the tire) is only 8 mm different (622 mm for 700c vs 630 mm for 27") and that's on the diameter. For a rack you're more interested in the radius so you're only really looking at 4 mm. I think the lack of mention of 27" in the description of the rack is because 27" is an uncommon size these days.

Comment: My confusion was not so much the size of the tires but the amount of clearance a rack might have. I've never used one and had no reference other than the sizes listed. I have come to the same conclusion as above and will order the rack without worry.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: And thanks for asking the question, that's a cool looking rack I hadn't seen before. Good luck with it. Do come back with the definitive answer!